# If X follows a Poisson distribution with mean 0.5, find E[(X+1)!]

Tags: poisson-distribution, expected-value

Its a competitive exam question

I know the Poisson pdf and how to find its expectation.
and also know that E[(X+1)(X)(X-1)..(2)(1)]=E[(X+1)!]

But then I really cannot proceed any further..I am stuck with this factorial part.. cant understand what to do with it!

Please help.

Comment: This looks like an exercise question. Please follow the guidelines at http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info  (show what you tried)

Comment: Its a competitive exam question and  I know E[(X+1)(X)..(2)(1)]=E[(X+1)!] But then I really cannot proceed any further..I am stuck with this factorial part.. cant understand what to do with it!

Comment: Did you check the guidelines? (You are supposed to add the tag). Anyway, hint: how would you compute $E[f(X)]$ for some function$f$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$E[(X+1)!]=\sum_{x=0}^\infty(x+1)!\frac{ \mu^{x}e^{-\mu}}{x!}=\sum_{x=0}^\infty(x+1)\mu^xe^{-\mu}=e^{-\mu}\sum_{x=0}^\infty(x+1)\mu^x$$

Next you need to find what is $\sum_{x=0}^\infty(x+1)\mu^x$

It is $$1+2\mu+3\mu^2+4\mu^3+...$$
Since $\mu=0.5$ this power series will converge.

I calculate it equals to $4$,you check it by yourself.